# SQL Find Max Value and Number of Rows Whic Are Equal to That Value

Tags: sql

Given a table, I am trying to find Max Months * Hackos and number of ID's with the max Months * Hackos value.

I tried the below code but it seems we cant use Max clause in the inner select.

```
SELECT MAX(MONTHS * HACKOS) AS MAXIMUM_HACKOS,
(SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM HACKER WHERE MONTHS*HACKOS = MAX(MONTHS*HACKOS)) AS NUMBER_OF_HACKERS
FROM HACKER ;
```

Correct expected output is 144 and 2 but my code is wrong.

[image: Sample Input]

Comment: 1. MySql doesn't use T-SQL - only SQL Server and Sybase are using T-SQL. 2. Please avoid posting images of your data. Instead, post sample data as formatted DDL and DML statements so that people can copy and paste it to a test environment.

Comment: @Furkanaracan . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT MAX(MONTHS * HACKOS) FROM HACKER
```

in the `WHERE` clause and then aggregate:

```
SELECT MAX(MONTHS * HACKOS) AS MAXIMUM_HACKOS,
       COUNT(*) AS NUMBER_OF_HACKERS
FROM HACKER
WHERE MONTHS * HACKOS = (SELECT MAX(MONTHS * HACKOS) FROM HACKER)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select     top 1
           MONTHS * HACKOS,
           count(*)
from       HACKER
group by   MONTHS * HACKOS
order by   MONTHS * HACKOS desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Can this solve your problem?

```
SELECT ID, NAME, MAX(MAXIMUM_HACKOS) FROM ( SELECT ID, NAME, ( MONTHS * HACKOS) as MAXIMUM_HACKOS FROM HACKER) A LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  NAME FROM HACKER GROUP BY  ID, NAME, MONTHS, MONTHS * HACKOS having MONTHS * HACKOS  > 100  AND MONTHS < 10   order by ID
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 2 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.